# Make ASP.NET Calendar Control Skip Years

Tags: asp.net, calendar, asp.net-3.5

By default, it seems that the standard Asp.NET calendar control can only scroll on a month-by-month basis (using the back and forward link buttons on the control).

Is there a way to customise this control to add paging links which will skip by a year in either direction?

I'm using .NET version 3.5 if that's any help.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to use the ASP.NET AJAX calendar, it allows clicking the title of the calendar to "zoom out" to selecting a month or a year, and you can navigate by year or decade (respectively).

See a demo here:
http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/calendar/calendar.aspx

Comment: Ah this old chestnut. This is a really nice calendar control, but I've had soooo many problems in the past using the ajax toolkit that I don't want to go down that route.

Comment: you should try it one more time, some of the pieces are invaluable

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#dropdown-month-year

Good luck!